# How I add 2 namespaces to a xml documento with XNamespace

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to create a xml with 2 namespaces, one without any prefix and other with prefix. My problem it putting both as attributes.

I'm tried many solutions, some give wrong output, others error code, like "System.Xml.XmlException: 'The prefix '' cannot be redefined from "

```
XNamespace ns1 = "http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/servico_enviar_lote_rps_envio.xsd", tc = "http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/tipos_complexos.xsd";
            el.Xmlns = "http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/servico_enviar_lote_rps_envio.xsd";

XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8",""),
                new XElement(ns1+"EnviarLoteRpsEnvio",
                  //  new XAttribute("xmlns" ,ns1), <- HERE IS THE ISSUE
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "tc", "http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/tipos_complexos.xsd"),
                       new XElement("LoteRps",
                new XElement(tc + "NumeroLote",loteRps.NumeroLote),
                   new XElement(tc + "CpfCnpj",
                        new XElement(tc + "Cnpj", cnpj.Cnpj)
                                )
                        , new XElement(tc + "InscricaoMunicipal", loteRps.InscricaoMunicipal)
                        , new XElement(tc + "QuantidadeRps", loteRps.QuantidadeRps)
                        , ListaRps
                        )));



            string loteenvio = "-env-loterps.xml";
            string filename = cnpj.Cnpj + loteRps.NumeroLote + loteenvio;

            xdoc.Save(filename);
```

My actual result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnviarLoteRpsEnvio xmlns:tc="http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/tipos_complexos.xsd" xmlns="http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/servico_enviar_lote_rps_envio.xsd">
  <LoteRps xmlns="">
    <tc:NumeroLote>1</tc:NumeroLote>
    <tc:CpfCnpj>
      <tc:Cnpj>123456789</tc:Cnpj>
    </tc:CpfCnpj>
```

When I need is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnviarLoteRpsEnvio xmlns="http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/servico_enviar_lote_rps_envio.xsd" xmlns:tc="http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/tipos_complexos.xsd">
  <LoteRps>
    <tc:NumeroLote>1</tc:NumeroLote>
    <tc:CpfCnpj>
      <tc:Cnpj>123456789</tc:Cnpj>
    </tc:CpfCnpj>
```

Comment: Why don't you use exactly the same code for "LoteRps" node as you used for "EnviarLoteRpsEnvio" ( `new XElement(ns1+"EnviarLoteRpsEnvio"` as both must have the same namespace)?

Comment: Because it is not an Element, is a property of the "EnviarLoteRpsEnvio" element.

Comment: XML does not have "properties" - it only have elements and attributes. I'm completely confused by what you mean " it is not an Element, is a property"...

Comment: I mean Attribute, was a mistake on naming. I found solution, posted below. Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution!
I refer to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-create-a-document-with-namespaces-linq-to-xml) and finally solved it with this code:

```
 XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8",""),
                new XElement(ns1+"EnviarLoteRpsEnvio"
                    ,new XAttribute ("xmlns","http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/servico_enviar_lote_rps_envio.xsd")
                    ,new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "tc", "http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/tipos_complexos.xsd")
                       ,new XElement(ns1+"LoteRps",
                new XElement(tc + "NumeroLote",loteRps.NumeroLote),
```

My great catch was the "ns1+" before the child element, which result in this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnviarLoteRpsEnvio xmlns="http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/servico_enviar_lote_rps_envio.xsd" xmlns:tc="http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/tipos_complexos.xsd">
  <LoteRps>
    <tc:NumeroLote>1</tc:NumeroLote>
    <tc:CpfCnpj>
```